# Problema con version de Java: Android Studio (version 2021.1) X Unable to determine bundled Java version

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter, windows, sdk

Estoy usando windows 10 Pro, al momento de correr mi proyecto flutter, me sale que la app se detuvo en el emulador.

Al correr flutter doctor obtengo eso:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.3, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.19044.2006], locale es-CO)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.4)
[!] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

He buscado incansablemente cada solución pero ninguna me resulta. Incluso cambie variables de entorno.

Comment: segun [esto](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15514#issuecomment-373329235) se resuelve eliminando la versión anterior de la carpeta de Android studio e instalando una nueva

Comment: Asi es, eso es lo que me acaba de dar solución. Era cuestion de eliminar las carpetas de android studio en la ruta C:\Program Files\Android e instalarlo nuevamente. Al correr flutter doctor marcaba 0 issues